# PIL OverflowError on loading PIL.Image.fromArray

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to store large images using pillow 3.3.1 on python 3.4. These images tend to be in the range from 1 to 4 GB, as uint8 RGB pixels. Linux and OSX give me the same result.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

imgArray = np.random.randint(255, size=(39000, 35000, 3)).astype(np.uint8)
print("buffer size:", imgArray.size)
print("image max bytes:", 2**32)
pilImage = Image.fromarray(imgArray)
```

I get the following output

```
buffer size: 4095000000
image max bytes: 4294967296

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "storeLargeImage.py", line 6, in <module>
    pilImage = Image.fromarray(imgArray)
  File "/home/mpesavento/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2189, in fromarray
    return frombuffer(mode, size, obj, "raw", rawmode, 0, 1)
  File "/home/mpesavento/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2139, in frombuffer
    return frombytes(mode, size, data, decoder_name, args)
  File "/home/mpesavento/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2074, in frombytes
    im.frombytes(data, decoder_name, args)
  File "/home/mpesavento/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 736, in frombytes
    s = d.decode(data)
OverflowError: size does not fit in an int
```

The buffer is smaller than the max I think PIL uses in python 3, which I thought used a uint32 for the buffer length. PIL in python 2 uses an int32, making the max 2**31-1.

This bug comes up before we determine the codec for storing. For example, I would like to either store lossless png or tif, via
`pilImage.save(BytesIO(), format="png")`
or
`pilImage.save(BytesIO(), format="tiff")`

How can one go about saving an image larger than 2 GB (2147483647 bytes)?

Edit:
It looks like it should have been [fixed a while ago](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/436). Not sure why the problem still shows up.

Comment: Looks like it's an [open issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1475).

Comment: A library that isn't pure Python may still be limited to 32-bit integers.

Answer (score 2):

I realize you asked about PIL, but you could try [libvips](https://github.com/libvips). It specializes in large images (images larger than your available RAM) and should have no problems with your 4gb files. There are some [speed and memory use benchmarks on the vips website](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/wiki/Speed-and-memory-use).

For example, I just did:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyvips
>>> x = pyvips.Image.perlin(100000, 100000, uchar=True)
>>> x.write_to_file("x.tif", bigtiff=True)
>>>
$ ls -l x.tif
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 10000012844 Oct  7 11:43 x.tif
```

Makes an 10gb, 8 bit, 100,000 x 100,000 pixel image of Perlin noise. It takes a little while, of course --- the final write is about three minutes on my laptop and needs 100MB of RAM. The Python binding is documented [here](https://libvips.github.io/pyvips/index.html). You can [move images between numpy and vips](https://libvips.github.io/pyvips/intro.html#numpy-and-pil).